# Clear a group of cache in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching

I am saving a list to cache. so that there is no need to go to the database eache time when the list needs.

here is the code

```
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCategoriesByParentId(int parentCategoryId)
    {
        string cacheKey = "PC" + parentCategoryId.ToString();
        DateTime expiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> categoryList ;
        categoryList = HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;
        if (categoryList == null)
        {
            categoryList = GetCategoryList(parentCategoryId);      // getting category from database         
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(cacheKey, categoryList, null, expiration, TimeSpan.Zero, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
        }
        return categoryList;

    }
```

My problem is when a new category is added to the database ,i am still gettting old category list .the list do not contain new category..How can clear the cache ( only category cache) after adding or changing a category

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you insert a new category to the database I suppose you have the parent category id into which this category was inserted so you could remove it from the cache:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("PC" + parentCategoryId);
```

Now if the adding of a new category is not done by your application and you have no control over it you may take a look at [cache expiration with SQL dependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx).

Comment: @Darin.Thanks for your answer.That code only remove a single list cahe with that category id . right ? .But i  want to remove all category list caches..because the changed category may added in another list that already cached.All caches are adding by me

Comment: @Null Pointer, yes it removes a single cache entry. If you wanted to remove all cache entries you could for example loop through them and check if the key stats with `PC` and if it does, remove it.

Comment: ,Can i set any type of cache dependency ? While adding a cache the third parameter is cache dependency. i provided null there now.